# Filter Off API Response

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am building an App that is going to populate a picker from API data.

The problem is the API data also comes with results that I DO NOT want the user to be able to select.

For example.

The data comes in with the following information.

```
Object {
  "buildings": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "0436",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "1232",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Loading Dock",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Print Shop",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "0189",
    }
]}
```

When I set the data.. I don't want to save the ones with Numbers.

```
const handleBuildings = async () => {
    const data = await axios
      .get(`API URL`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Auth',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setBuildingList(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fairly simple filter on array and only return wanted values like this.
This will only return buildings.name which is not a number above og equal to 0.

You can use like this:

```
const handleBuildings = async () => {
const data = await axios
  .get(`API URL`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Auth',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    setBuildingList(response.data.buildings.filter(building => {
      if (Number(building.name) >= 0) {
        console.log('name is a number');
      } else {
          return building;
      }
    }));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

};

```js
data = {
  "buildings": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "0436",
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "1232",
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Loading Dock",
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Print Shop",
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "0189",
    }
]};

let actaulBuildings = data.buildings.filter(building => {
    if (Number(building.name) >= 0) {
        console.log('name is a number');
    } else {
        return building;
    }
});

console.log(actaulBuildings);
```